# Do the eyes play any role in producing the visual experiences you have during dreaming?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, dreaming, human-eye

Sometimes, you remember a vivid picture of a dream that you saw. What is the role of your eye in this experience? Please provide me with the answer that is as simple as possible since I am in Class 10(Grade 10).

Answer (score 2):

Your eye doesn't play a part in your dream aside from giving you the basic images which your brain later used to form the dream. The visual image in your dream comes from your brain itself.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's best to add references, or list the literature you've cited. This is a scientific site. Please format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The cerebrum is the centre of any unconsious activities that take place in our body. So there is hardly any part played by the eyes in visualising a dream. The brain does the visualising part

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! While this may answer the question it lacks support from references in the scientific literature. Un-referenced answers may be challenged or deleted.